# Unable to build gcc branch for cilk

Tags: gcc, makefile, cilk, cilk-plus

I am trying to build the cilk branch from the branch downloaded form svn by this command:
`svn co http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/cilkplus-4_7-branch/`

The tutorial I am using to install is :[this one](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-build-gcc-cilkplus-brance-in-64bit-ubuntu-1204/)

In step 5 line 9 I get this error:

`ar: elem-function-common.o: No such file or directory`

Though the error is pretty explanatory in itself but I was unable to find that creation of any such file 'elem-function-common.o' in the log of commands of make -j3 (step 5 line 9). Can somebody help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try building out with other branch [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/cilkplus/) and it compiles and installs easily. The other branch is untested so it is advised not to use it(as of the post of the date)